# VBA: code makes my page jump when running

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I have use a code from the internet and customized it for myself, when I run this, which does do what I want it to, it takes for ages and my page seems to jump a lot as its running.
It run's through over 2000 rows to find the data.

Any Help to improve this and stop it from jumping would be great

```
Option Explicit
Sub Stock_Update()

Dim datasheet As Worksheet
Dim reportsheet As Worksheet
Dim Month As String
Dim frow As Long
Dim i As Integer

Set datasheet = Sheet10
Set reportsheet = Sheet9
Month = reportsheet.Range("c3").Value

reportsheet.Range("A7:l200").ClearContents

datasheet.Select
frow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 7 To frow
If Cells(i, 1) = Month Then
Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 12)).Copy
reportsheet.Select

Range("A200").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats

datasheet.Select

End If


Next i

reportsheet.Select

Range("A6").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your screen is flickering is the constant use of select between the two sheets. In general you can avoid this by using `application.screenuptdating = false`.

But in the end you should avoid selecting at all - please read [How to avoid select](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/16578424).

If you only need the values to be copied, you don't need copy/paste actions. This will increase performance too.

I updated your code - with both scenarios possible (copying values only or - as you did - copying formulas and numberformatting as well - just switch the the comment accordingly

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Const MonthRange As String = "C3"
Private Const rowStartReport As Long = 7

Public Sub createMonthlyReport()

ApplicationScreenUpdating = False

Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim wsReport As Worksheet

Set wsData = Sheet10   'you can set the (code)name in the VBA-Editor - then you wouldn't need this
Set wsReport = Sheet9

Dim Month As String

With wsReport
    Month = wsReport.Range(MonthRange).Value
    wsReport.Cells(rowStartReport, 1).CurrentRegion.ClearContents
End With
    

Dim iRowData As Long, iRowReport As Long

Dim r As Range, rgToCopy As Range, cTarget As Range

For Each r In wsData.UsedRange.Rows
    If r.Cells(1, 1) = Month Then
        Set rgToCopy = r.Cells(, 2).Resize(, 11)    'adjust this to your needs
        Set cTarget = wsReport.Cells(rowStartReport + iRowReport, 1)
        
        'change this to your needs
        'copyValues rgToCopy, cTarget     'this is faster
        copyValuesAndFormats rgToCopy, cTarget   'this copies formulas as well
        
        iRowReport = iRowReport + 1
        
    End If
Next

wsReport.Select

wsReport.Range("A6").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

'Two Generic routines to copy values etc.

Private Sub copyValues(rgSource As Range, cTarget As Range)
'this copies values only
With rgSource
    cTarget.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = rgSource.Value
End With
End Sub

Private Sub copyValuesAndFormats(rgSource As Range, cTarget As Range)
'this copies values, formulas and numberformats
rgSource.Copy
cTarget.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is so much better and works perfect.